# Why is this use of the [] operator causing a compiler error?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I wrote this quick function to get familiar with `boost::program_options`.  Please note that `po` is a namespace alias, defined thus:  `namespace po = boost::program_options`.

```
int application(po::variables_map* vm)
{
    std::cout << vm << std::endl;
    std::cout << *vm["infile"].value();
    // also tried:  std::cout << *vm["infile"]

    return SUCCESS;
}  //application
```

When I comment out the second line in the function body, the application successfully compiles and prints the address of `vm`.  However, when I try to compile with the function appearing as it does here, I get the following compiler insult:

```
invalid types ‘boost::program_options::variables_map*[const char [7]]’ for array subscript
```

I should note that replacing the second line with `std::cout << vm->count("infile")` returns  `1`.

What have I done wrong?  Am I abusing a boost construct or am I getting mixed up in (de)referencing `vm`?

**Update**

Following the suggestion that I pass by reference to avoid the operator precedence issue, I rewrote my function thus:

```
int application(po::variables_map& vm)
{
    std::cout << &vm << std::endl;
    std::cout << vm["infile"].value();

    return SUCCESS;
}  //application
```

I'm now getting a different error:

```
no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const boost::program_options::variable_value’)
```

What have I done wrong here?

**Edit:** I'd appreciate being told why my question is being downvoted.  Is it too basic?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Just a wild guess, try this `(*vm)["infile"]`.

Comment: Something worth memorizing: `[]` has higher precedence than `*` and `p->x` is sugar for `(*p).x` (more or less)

Comment: Although `(*vm).["infile"]` will probably work, you're probably better off eliminating the problem -- pass `vm` by reference instead of passing a pointer.

Comment: @RayToal, ah, yikes!  That's indeed very good to know!  It all makes sense now... My compiler is trying to dereference the result of `[]` on the pointer, correct?

Comment: @JerryCoffin, duly noted!  I can't quite understand why a `.` is required, though.  Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Yes, the meaning of `*vm["infile"]` is `*(vm["infile"]).  The cool thing is that `*` and `[]` are just regular operators and you can use parentheses anywhere in the expression to make yourself very clear.  I tend to always use them when mixing `*` and `[]`.

Comment: @blz: In general, postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix ones.

Comment: @blz: That would have very little to do with the language, and a lot to do with my (lack of) typing skill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[]` operator has a higher precedence than the unary `*` operator. Thus, `*vm["infile"]` is the same as `*(vm["infile"])`, but you want `(*vm)["infile"]`.

Comment: thank you for your answer!  I tried rewriting this to pass-by-reference (as suggested by JerryCoffin).  I'm now getting an entirely different error.  Do you have any suggestions?